# not defined php function called

Tags: php, function, undefined

I have the following code, which seems to work:

`$this->getSoapClient()->processShipment()`.

My issue is that

`(new \ReflectionClass(get_class($this->getSoapClient())))->getMethods())`

Above code does not show any "processShipment()" method, only standard SoapClient methods.
Yet, i need the source of `processShipment()`.

How can i find the definition of the function?
How is it even possible that that function successfully gets called without being defined?

Comment: after `get_class($this->getSoapClient())))` remove one closing bracket.

The correct is `(new \ReflectionClass(get_class($this->getSoapClient()))->getMethods())` . Check if this is the error.

Comment: Because it is defined somewhere on remote web service which you are calling using `soap` protocol via `soapclient`. This is called - remote procedure call. Try call `SoapClient::__getFunctions()` it should be there

Comment: Thank you! seems reasonable to me...does SoapClient override some sort of generic method then?

Comment: It provides you a tool to interact with `SoapServer`, I guess it has magic `__call()` method where logic contained